# What's the reference for this dhyana shloka?

Tags: vishnu, shloka, reference-request

> Shanka chakra dharam devam
> Chatur bahum kiritinam
> Sarvayudhair upethancha
> Garudopari samsthitham
> Sanakadhi munindraisthu sarva devair upAsitham
> Shree Bhoomi sahitham devam udaya dhithya sannibam
> Pradharodhya sahasramshu mandalopari samsthithan
> Sarva lokasya rakshartham ....
> Anantham nithyamevacha
> Abhayam varadhanchaiva prayaChantham mudhanvitham
> Evam dhayathva Harim nithyam Parabrahma swaroopinam

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it can be traced to one or more than one puranas, the [Dhyanam](https://html.scribdassets.com/7b54ixc8e84zwkf8/images/118-97bc1c9c61.jpg) can be found in 19th patalam of [Aanadikalpa-tantra](https://www.scribd.com/doc/296948904/Annada-Kalpa-Tantra-S-N-Khandelwal) under the [Nama-Traya Mahatmya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29182/21353).